# Linux C TCP Socket client/server with redirected output application

Tags: c, linux, redirect, tcp

Let me start out by saying that this is a homework assignment for an operating systems class and I am not a programmer, especially not in C.  I've been at this for a week now and I am simply stuck and I need help.  I have to create TCP client and server applications where linux commands are typed into the client, executed on the server and the output is redirected back to the client.  I understand the concept and I have it 90+% working.  Commands like "ls", "ls -lpq", "cat somefile", "man somecommand" all work fine.  Where I run into trouble is with commands that do not return any information like "mkdir newdir" (if the directory already exists it works fine because I get a response).  This is all new to me but it seems to me that my problem is with the servers recv command blocking because there is no information to receive.  I don't know how to get past this, I have been working this one issue for a week.  I'm running out of time and I also have to implement file upload and download and I don't know where to begin there but I can't even start to work on that until I get past this issue.

Thanks

```
    // this is where I think the problem is
    while ((rcvd_bytes = recv(sock_fd, recv_str, sizeof(recv_str), 0)) > 0 ) {
        // Zero out the inputCopy buffer
        memset(&inputCopy, 0, sizeof(inputCopy)+1);

        // Copy the recv_str into a new string so that
        // we can work with it.
        strcpy(inputCopy, recv_str);

        argcount = parsecommand(inputCopy, args);

        //Send the message back to client
        dup2(sock_fd, 1);

        if((status = forkAndExecute(args)) != 0) {
            //printf("Command %s returned %d.\n", args[0], status);
        }

            // as a test is I uncomment the following line mkdir newdir
            // returns but the following commands are messed up - as I expect.
        //printf("\n");

        memset(&recv_str, 0, sizeof(recv_str)+1);
        fflush(stdout);
    }  

    if(rcvd_bytes == 0) {
    puts("Client disconnected");
    fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(rcvd_bytes == -1) {
    perror("recv failed");
    exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your problem description, my suspicion is the client code rather than the server code -- or, actually, the protocol you've implicitly created between the two.

It looks like you're just sending the output of the command directly back to the client by using `dup2` to point standard output at the socket.  Presumably, the client then reads from the socket to get the output from the command?  What does the client do when it sends a command to the server and then gets no reply?  A command like `mkdir` will send nothing back.  Is it waiting forever for the server to send command output?

In general, for a synchronous client/server protocol (one where the client sends a command and the server sends a response before the client sends another command), you have to agree on a protocol between the client and the server to clearly indicate when the server is done sending data back and the client should send its next command.  You may need to add some way for the server to tell the client that the command completed but sent no output.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that the way it's designed, it reads a line and sends it, then it expects something back (which it reads all at once), dumps it on your screen, and waits for another line.  I don't think bidirectional access works.

Comment: Yeah, that's my thought too.  So when the command doesn't send anything back, the client blocks forever waiting for the output.

Comment: I've been looking at this to long.  The client recv code is what I was originally concentrating on but I convinced myself it was the server.  The client code is // Receive reply from server
   if ((n = recv(sockfd, reply, 10000, 0)) < 0) {
    puts("Receive failed");
    break;
   }
   //n = recv(sockfd, reply, 10000, 0);
   reply[n]= '\0';
   fputs(reply, stdout);'

Comment: Yeah, that will block waiting for the server to send something, so if the server never sends any output back from the command, I'm pretty sure that will just wait forever.  You were on the right track with the idea of having the server send a newline after the command output.  I think you need something like that so that the client gets some output no matter what the command does.

Comment: Thanks all!  rra and Wug - you redirected me back to the client when I was stuck on the server.  – JB0x2D1, I spent way too many hours trying to understand select() by just reading so I decided to dig in and start coding.  I ended up scrapping the client code and starting over.  For the most part I understand it but I have some more reading to do.  Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to use [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) .

```
if(select(fdmax+1, &my_fdset, 0, 0, NULL) > 0) // there is data available to be read
    recv(...)
```

where `fdmax` is the largest file descriptor (select wants that +1) and `my_fdset` is a file descriptor set that you add file descriptors to using `FD_SET(sockfd, &my_fdset);`.

This will only receive when there is data available.  Hope that helps.

**EDIT :**

I asked a similar question when I was writing a simple client/server program to send/recv strings over a TCP socket.  I posted the code that I ended up using on that thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513588/c-pthreads-sending-and-recving-on-a-socket-worked-separately-but-not-togeth).  Mine is different in that I wanted one program to send and recv but if you look at my sender or receiver functions, you may be able to adapt something to make your program do what you want.

Comment: Have an upvote for reading my mind.  Also, `poll` is a system call with similar functionality.  You can read the documentation for it on the command line with `man 2 poll`.

Comment: @Wug - Thanks! I literally just finished a similar program last night :)

Comment: I've been looking at this to long.  The client recv code is what I was originally concentrating on but I convinced myself it was the server.  The client code is:

    // Receive reply from server
    if ((n = recv(sockfd, reply, 10000, 0)) < 0) {
        puts("Receive failed");
 break;
    }
    //n = recv(sockfd, reply, 10000, 0);
    reply[n]= '\0';
    fputs(reply, stdout);
but I must not understand it correctly.  I thought the code would break when it fails this condition: if ((n = recv(sockfd, reply, 10000, 0)) < 0) is that not the case?

Comment: sorry about the code format, I tried three times and I can't get that to work either.

Comment: `if(n=recv(...))` will set n to bytes received or -1 on error as per the [recv man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv).  Basically, just for error checking.  It will still attempt to `recv()` even if nothing is there, thus blocking.  In other words, it is waiting to `recv()` a message that never comes so the loop condition is never evaluated as false (unless there is some error condition and `recv()` returns -1).  So `use if(select(...))` then your `if(n=recv(...))`.  Change the outer loop to something like `while(1)` then check for some condition in order to `break` out.